# Find the pseudo-inverse of the matrix $A$ without computing singular values of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

Consider the following Least Square Minimization problem:$min_{x \in \mathbb C^3} |x_1 +x_3-3|^2+|x_2 -x_3|^2+|x_1+x_3-4|^2$
Find the pseudo-inverse of the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 1  \\
    0       & 1 & -1  \\
    1       & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$
without computing singular values of $A$.

It seems we cannot use normal equations to denote $A^{+}=(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}$ 
since $A^{T}A^{-1}$ is not invertible. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a pseudoinverse?

Comment: @sranthrop presumably [Moore-Penrose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Definition)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes.

Comment: Why not just sovlve the system $AA^+A=A,A^+AA^+=A^+,AA^+=(AA^+)^T,A^+A=(A^+A)^T$? Do you have to do your calculations by hand?

Comment: @sranthrop How to solve?

Comment: Well, just set $A^+=\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{pmatrix}$ and write down the four equations above. You'll get a linear system with 9 variables, that has a unique solution.

Comment: @sranthrop Thanks! I happened to know someone wrote the answer but I don't know why. It's like this. So, it's written like if we consider the minimum norm solution of the least square problem $$\underset{{x \in \mathbb C^3}}  \min  |x_1 +x_3 -b_1|^2 + |x_2 -x_3 -b_2|^2 +|x_1 +x_3 -b_3|^2$$ and the solution has the form $x_1 +x_3 =(b_1 + b_3)/2$ and $x_2 -x_3 -b_2=0$ and $-x_1 +x_2 +x_3=0$

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods to calculate $A^+$ without calculating singular values. Here are two of them.

**Method 1.**

Use the formula $A^+=\lim_{t\to0}A^T(AA^T+tI)^{-1}$. In your case, you should get something like
\begin{align*}
A^+&=\lim_{t\to0}A^T(AA^T+tI)^{-1}\\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\pmatrix{1&0&1\\ 0&1&0\\ 1&-1&1}\pmatrix{t+2&-1&2\\ -1&t+2&-1\\ 2&-1&t+2}^{-1}\\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac1{t^2+6t+6}
\pmatrix{t+2&2&t+2\\ 1&t+4&1\\ t+1&-t-2&t+1}\\
&=\frac16\pmatrix{2&2&2\\ 1&4&1\\ 1&-2&1}.
\end{align*}

---

**Method 2.**

Use the property that if $X$ has orthonormal columns or $Y$ has orthonormal rows, then $(XY)^+=Y^+X^+$. Decompose $A$ as the product $\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&1\\ 1&0}\pmatrix{1&0&1\\ 0&1&-1}$. Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation gives
\begin{align*}
A
&=\left[
\pmatrix{\frac1{\sqrt{2}}&0\\ 0&1\\ \frac1{\sqrt{2}}&0}
\pmatrix{\sqrt{2}\\ &1}
\right]
\left[
\pmatrix{\sqrt{2}&0\\ -\frac1{\sqrt{2}}&\sqrt{\frac32}}
\pmatrix{\frac1{\sqrt{2}}&0&\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac1{\sqrt{6}}&\sqrt{\frac23}&-\frac1{\sqrt{6}}}
\right]\\
&=\underbrace{\pmatrix{\frac1{\sqrt{2}}&0\\ 0&1\\ \frac1{\sqrt{2}}&0}}_{X}
\underbrace{\pmatrix{2&0\\ -\frac1{\sqrt{2}}&\sqrt{\frac32}}}_{Y}
\underbrace{\pmatrix{\frac1{\sqrt{2}}&0&\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac1{\sqrt{6}}&\sqrt{\frac23}&-\frac1{\sqrt{6}}}}_{Z}.
\end{align*}
Since $X$ has orthonormal columns, $Y$ is invertible and $Z$ has orthonormal rows, we have
$$
A^+=(XYZ)^+=Z^+Y^+X^+=Z^TY^{-1}X^T.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
 \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} = \frac{1}{6}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 2 & -2 & 2 \\
 1 & -4 & 1 \\
 1 &  2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$